# URL rewriting how to add extra condition

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, seo

I'm trying to redirect my website urls from `example.com` to `www.example.com`.
By using the code below, It works partially; All website's urls starting by `example.com` are redirected to `www.example.com`.

However, while using the "`index.php?slug=`" in the website url: `example.com/index.php?slug=About` instead of being redirected to `www.example.com/About`, the url is redirected to `www.example.com/index.php?slug=About`.

So, it's result that both urls (`www.example.com/About` and `www.example.com/index.php?slug=About`) are working and showing same results.

Any idea how to handle it, to avoid duplicate content on search engine? Which conditions should I add here?

Thanks.

Here is the htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# htaccess custom error messages
ErrorDocument 400 "Ooops - Bad request!"
ErrorDocument 403 "Strictly forbidden.."
ErrorDocument 401 "Speak friend and enter"
ErrorDocument 500 "Server gone wild.."

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# htaccess custom error messages
ErrorDocument 400 "Ooops - Bad request!"
ErrorDocument 403 "Strictly forbidden.."
ErrorDocument 401 "Speak friend and enter"
ErrorDocument 500 "Server gone wild.."

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

You should be doing the *www*-check before any `index.php` rewriting.

In addition (and this is just an enhancement/fix to your code), you should not be conditioning `ErrorDocument` to `mod_rewrite`, so it has been moved outside of the block. You also had `RewriteEngine on` specified twice. You only need to specify this once.

Comment: Thanks Mike! You' were really helpful